# Does Sql Server caches parameterized anonymous blocks?

Tags: sql-server, cache, ado.net

"Anonymous block" is a term from Oracle. But speaking of the thing for sql server

```sql
Declare
   ....
Begin
    begin trans
 . . . 
    commit
End
```

If I send this SQL in parameterized form to the server via ADO.NET, will it be cached and reused or it will be recompiled every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my brief reading on **Anonymous Blocks** in Oracle, this is essentially just an ad-hoc query in SQL Server. Yes, ad-hoc queries are cached in the [**query plan cache**](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-sql-server-query-plan-cache/) of SQL Server, and therefore on subsequent runs won't be recompiled, for as long as they stay in the cache. (The query plan cache has mechanisms to remove old and/or rarely used plans from the cache based on the busyness of the server.)